# How to list all dynamically created views in an activity?

Tags: android, dynamic, resources, view

I'd like to see all the dynamically created Buttons, TextViews, etc before (or even after) setContentView() shows them on the screen. I have a loose understanding that this relates to the Context and the Activity, but concretely I don't know where these dynamic views exist / how they are put together at runtime.

And if they are shown at runtime is there a way to list all of them?

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.addView(button1);
    layout.addView(button2);
    layout.addView(button3);
    setContentView(layout);
```

The buttons SHOULD exist somewhere (I am so sure they exist in the Context!!) but there is no way (that I have found) of locating these dynamically created views.
Please and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you are going to need to display these kinds of things on the screen, then you should keep a reference to them somewhere.  This is a common pattern, if you dynamically create a button, you need to stuff them in a `List` (for example).  You shouldn't need to get all the views if you program like this, and even if you easily could (typically in GUIs, you can, either by reflection, or something equally tacky mechanism) it wouldn't be organized in any kind of logical structure that would relate the things in the layout to the logical layout dictated by the application.  So instead, when you dynamically create views, stuff them somewhere like a list so you can iterate through it later.